# Response's content-disposition cannot be set to attachment while using jfree and itext together

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext, jfreechart

My requirement is to put the chart's generated by JFreeChart in to my PDF document

To display the list of charts, am getting list of BufferedImage objects

```
private BufferedImage generateChartForPDF (DefaultCategoryDataset dataset,String threadName) {
        String title = "Skill  : "+threadName ;

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(title, "Work Completion",
                "Perce %", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true,
                false);

        return chart.createBufferedImage(500, 300) ;
    }
```

From this i fill a list of buffered image and am filling the chart in PDF in below way

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document pdfDocument = new Document();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, baos);
setGraphImagesInPDF(pdfDocument, buffImageList) ;
private void setGraphImagesInPDF (Document pdfDocument,List<BufferedImage> buffImageList) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        for (BufferedImage bufferedImage : buffImageList) {
            Image image = Image.getInstance(bufferedImage,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            pdfDocument.newPage();
            image.setAbsolutePosition(300, 300) ;
            pdfDocument.add(image);
        }
    }
```

This is how i fill the chart inside my PDF. Now when i set the content-disposition to attachment, am not getting the response as attachment in  my UI, rather the browser is opening the PDF in another page

```
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
setResponseHeaders(response,"Data");
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

private void setResponseHeaders(HttpServletResponse response,String reportingType) {
        System.out.println("setting response headers .. ");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\""+reportingType+" Reports.pdf\"");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    }
```

Even though i set the content-dispostion type to attachment in response's header, this is not opening as attachment. The same works fine after removing the chart-part of the code. Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: (1) why is this question tagged itext/jfreechart. This question is about response header, isn't it? It doesn't matter if you use iText or JFreeChart. (2) Can you reproduce the problem on different machines, using different browsers? My guess is that you have a local configuration problem that isn't reproducable on every client machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bruno's comment, is not a iText/JFreechart question, rather a servlet/http question.

You must set response headers **before** you get the output stream: this is mandatory. I suggest you to set also the `content-length` header in `setResponseHeaders` method, like this:

```
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
```

So your code should be:

```
setResponseHeaders(response, baos, "Data");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Perfect !! It worked !! :-) "Headers first, writing next" :-)